# Determine with a proof the largest number which can be written as a product of natural numbers which have sum 2012

Tags: natural-numbers

I'm having trouble finding the largest number and proving it.

Comment: What’s the largest one that you can identify so far?

Answer (score 2):

Let the maximum product be $p$.
From AM-GM, we have
$$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}n \geq \left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^{1/n}$$
Hence, we get that
$$\dfrac{2012}n \geq p^{1/n}$$
Hence, we have that
$$p \leq \left(\dfrac{2012}n \right)^n$$
Now study the behavior of the function $f(x) = \left(\dfrac{2012}x \right)^x$ or equivalently the behavior of the function $g(x) = \log(f(x)) = x \log (2012) - x \log(x)$. We then have
$$g'(x) = \log(2012) - 1 - \log(x)$$
$$g'(x) = 0 \implies x = \dfrac{2012}e$$ Hence, $n \approx \dfrac{2012}e$ and to maximize the product all number must be more or less equal to $e$. Since, all the numbers are natural numbers, they must be either $2$ or $3$. Now make use of the fact that $2 + 2 + 2 = 3 + 3$ and $2^3 < 3^2$ to conclude that we need six hundred and seventy $3's$ and a $2$ to maximize the product.

Answer (score 1):

Use as many threes as you can, make up the remainder with twos, as necessary. Proof left to reader.